# Symfony - query sum

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, sum

I am writing a query  which will return amount of total spent money for that user. Total spent = sum of all transaction amounts, where type = spend. I have set my type field in a base to 'spend'..

It returns

> Invalid parameter: token type is not defined in the query.

My code.

```
public function getTotal(User $user, $type)
{
    $query = $this->getSpendingRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select("sum(p.amount) as total_amount")
        ->where('p.type = :spend')
        ->andWhere('p.user = :user')
        ->setParameters(['user' => $user,
                         'type' => $type])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    return $query;
}
```

and this is sql that is working so I don't know what am I doing wrong..

```
select user_id, sum(amount) as amount
from transaction
where type = 'spend'
group by user_id
```

Comment: Come on: `:spend` is not `type`

Comment: I want do define value of the field 'type' there.. Is there other way?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
->where('p.type = :spend')
```

with

```
->where('p.type = :type')
```

Comment: Are you really sure? Did you try it? `:spend` is the name of the variable in your query. And the error says clearly that it does not find a variable `type` in your query. Because you named it wrong.

Comment: Spend is the input value I enetred in a field 'type' in my db table.. where type = 'spend'
group by user_id

Comment: In your query you defined the variables ":spend" and ":user", but with `setParameters` you pass values for "type" and "user". This answer should actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
 public function getTotalSpent(User $user, $type = 'spend')
{
    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select("sum(p.amount) as total_amount")
        ->where('p.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('p.user = :user')
        ->setParameters(['user' => $user,
                         'type' => $type])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    return $query;
}
```